# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' when referencing _POST super global

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ads\register.php on line 5

This is not the full code, but a part of it. Why is that error being thrown?

```
$fname    = _POST['name[first]'];
$lname    = _POST['name[last]'];
$email    = _POST['email'];
$address1 = _POST['address[addr1]'];
$address2 = _POST['address[addr2]'];
$city     = _POST['address[city]'];
$state    = _POST['address[state]'];
$country  = _POST['address[country]'];
$phno     = _POST['number'];
$adtype   = _POST['select'];
```

Comment: Sidenote: `$_POST` is a [`superglobal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and must include the `$` sign. Replace all `_POST` with `$_POST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `$` in `$_POST` on all your lines. And your syntax for multi-dimensional arrays is incorrect.

```
$fname = $_POST['name']['first'];
```

When you have `name="name[first]"` in the HTML input element, PHP turns this into a nested array in `$_POST`, rather than using `name[first]` as the key.

Comment: You must have copied my answer incorrectly. Try again.

Comment: Thanks sir... The query has been solved.. :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$fname= $_POST['name']['first'];
```

Comment: It wouldn't fix a **syntax** error. How about some `$`?

Comment: yeah sorry, I didn't notice,

Answer (score 0):

When you see `syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ads\register.php on line 5`

You should always check your code on `line 5`, it has `invalid syntax`

In this case on line 5:

```
$fname    = _POST['name[first]'];
```

this is a `invalid syntax`

should replace with:

```
 $fname    = $_POST['name']['first'];
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone... The query has been solved.. :) :)